# System.Diagnostics.Trace/Debug on Windows CE 5.0 and Compact Framework 3.5

Tags: compact-framework, windows-ce

I'm working on a Windows CE 5.0 device using the .Net Compact Framework 3.5. The device has its own wireless connection and I'd like to use System.Diagnostics.Trace and the local network to monitor application activity, ideally using a listener (DebugView) on a desktop machine to monitor the .Net code running on the CE device.

I have two questions:

1) Is this possible using the Compact Framework 3.5?

2) If not is there another (simple) way which we can acheive it?

Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you're connected with the debugger in Studio, then you will get debug messages in the Debug view in Studio, but that's the only "pipe" that's built in. If you want those messages to go so some other debug listener, whether it's a disconnected instance of Studio or some other app, the compact framework does not inherently support this.
2. You could create a [TraceListener implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy72797k(v=VS.90).aspx) that does push the data out in whatever format you want.